# How to categorize items into sections in a tableView MasterViewController - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to categorize my items (city names) into 2 sections in a `SplitViewController` Sections to be named: Domestic and International.

I'm using a `enum` in the `dataModel` with an `init` in the `MasterViewController` This is what I have so far.

DataModel...

```
import UIKit

enum welcomeImage {
    case austin, athens, barcelona, losAngeles, newYork, palmSprings, paris, portland, reykjavik, rome
}

class Destination {
    let name: String
    var description: String
    var destinationType: String
    let imageName: welcomeImage

    init(name: String, description: String, destinationType: String, imageName: welcomeImage) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.destinationType = destinationType
        self.imageName = imageName

    }

func welcomeImage() -> UIImage? {
        switch self.imageName {
        case .athens:
            return UIImage(named: "Athens.jpg")
        case .austin:
            return UIImage(named: "Austin.jpg")
        case .barcelona:
            return UIImage(named: "Barcelona.jpg")
        case .losAngeles:
            return UIImage(named: "Los Angeles.jpg")
        case .newYork:
            return UIImage(named: "New York.jpg")
        case .palmSprings:
            return UIImage(named: "Palm Springs.jpg")

        }
    }
```

MasterViewController...

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    self.cities.append(Destination(name: "Austin, Texas", description: "The lonestar state, BBQ and live music! Just watch out for the fire ants and always bring a bottle of water where ever you go.", destinationType: "", imageName: .austin))
    self.cities.append(Destination(name: "Athens, Greece", description: "The birthplace of democracy. The freshest food in Europe! Being in Athens, you get a genuine feeling of antiquity.", destinationType: "", imageName: .athens))
    self.cities.append(Destination(name: "Barcelona, Spain", description: "Home of Gaudi and the epic construciton of La Sagrada Familia. The croissants in Barcelona are actually better than those in Paris.", destinationType: "", imageName: .barcelona))
    self.cities.append(Destination(name: "Los Angeles, California", description: "San Gabriel mountains, swimming pools, palm trees, beaches and high-energy...", destinationType: "", imageName: .losAngeles))
    self.cities.append(Destination(name: "New York, New York", description: "The big apple", destinationType: "", imageName: .newYork))
    self.cities.append(Destination(name: "Palm Springs, California", description: "Warm Desert Breezes", destinationType: "", imageName: .palmSprings))
}
```

Delegate methods...

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.cities.count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) 
        let city = self.cities[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = city.name
        if let imageView = cell.imageView, let itemImage = city.welcomeImage() {
            imageView.image = itemImage
        } else {
            cell.imageView?.image = nil
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Arrays in MasterViewController...

```
let sectionTitles: [String] = ["Domestic", "International"]

var domesticCity: [welcomeImage] = [.austin, .losAngeles, .newYork, .palmSprings]
var internationalCity: [welcomeImage] = [.athens, .barcelona]
```

I'm not sure what to place in `destinationType` that will sort the cities into the appropriate sections of Domestic and International in the `tableView`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for editing help @RyanPoolos

Comment: If you show your `numberOfSections` full method. And `numberOfRowsInSection` And `cellForItem...` we might be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to populate an array for each table section. Set destinationType to "Domestic" or "International" when you create each destination and add to self.cities. Once self.cities is complete, create self.domesticCities and self.internationalCities arrays, and go through self.cities and add each city to the proper destinationType array.

then:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(section == 0){
            return self.domesticCities.count
        } else if(section == 1){
            return self.internationalCities.count
        }
        return 0; // should never get here
    }
```

and likewise for cellForRowAt.

I do this same kind of thing to organize contacts based on first letter of name and support the right side thumb index (or whatever they call it). You can use a dictionary of arrays with destinationType 'keys' to manage multiple sections, but with only two you can explicitly define the arrays.

Comment: Thanks @FryAnEgg. The result wasn't quite as expected. I ended up with 2 sections with a mixture of the same Domestic and International Cites in each section.